# How to extract a substring by pattern ignoring a particular case in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Supposing, I have a string:

```
s = 'qwe rty uio'
```

I want to extract all entries by pattern `[a-z]+` ignoring the word `rty` with the help of a right regex pattern only (without any pretreatment). How do I do it?

I have tried this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?!rty)[a-z]+')
result = pattern.findall(s)
print(result)  # ['qwe']
```

But it found only the first entry... Which pattern is correct?

Comment: You may remove `rty` before running the regex - `pattern.findall(s.replace('rty', ''))`. Also, try [`r'\b(?!rty\b)[a-z]+'`](https://regex101.com/r/gicB8s/1) if you want to match any *whole word* other than `rty`.

Comment: I would like to do it with a correct regex pattern only. Your pattern didn't work.

Comment: "Didn't work" how? [**It works well**](https://ideone.com/5aXPga). What is the goal? Extract all words not having `rty` or not equal to `rty`?

Comment: It worked, I hadn't copied it carefully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all whole words in lowercase ASCII letters other than `rty` word, use

```
r'\b(?!rty\b)[a-z]+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gicB8s/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!rty\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `rty` substring immediately to the right of the current location followed with a trailing word boundary (if there can be any char but a lowercase ASCII letter, you may replace this `\b` with `(?![a-z])`)
- `[a-z]+` - 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters.

Below is a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5aXPga):

```
import re
rx = r"\b(?!rty\b)[a-z]+"
s = "qwe rty uio"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['qwe', 'uio']
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you don't even need a lookahead. just split on whitespaces and use a list comprehension:

```
import re

s = 'qwe rty uio'
words = [word for word in re.split(r'\s+', s) if word != 'rty']
print(words)
# ['qwe', 'uio']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/VuvFkz).